# Swift getting Nil when attempting to get value from key that exists

Tags: swift, dictionary, viewcontroller, applicationcontext

Im not sure why i am getting this nil error on optional when attempting to print. Can somebody provide any input? It doesn't make sense that I am able to output the value from the **aplicationContext**, however when I attempt to get value from **applicationContext["hearRate"]** i get nil.

```
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
        print("didReceiveApplicationContext\n\t\(applicationContext)")
        let hrValue = applicationContext["heartRate"] as? String
        print(applicationContext["hearRate"])
        print(hrValue)
        heartRate.text = hrValue
    }
```

```
console - output
2021-03-10 18:41:04.623716-0700 Trainer+[1824:759737] Metal API Validation Enabled
session active state
didReceiveApplicationContext
    ["heartRate": 00BPM]
nil
Optional("00BPM")
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file Trainer_/ViewController.swift, line 57
2021-03-10 18:41:04.999001-0700 Trainer+[1824:759754] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file Trainer_/ViewController.swift, line 57
```

Update - Ignore typo, found issue with IBOutlet

```
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
        print("didReceiveApplicationContext\n\t\(applicationContext)")
        let hrValue = applicationContext["heartRate"] as? String
        print(applicationContext["heartRate"])
        print(hrValue)
        //heartRate.text = hrValue
        heartRate.text = "test"
    }
```

```
2021-03-11 12:45:05.482464-0700 Trainer+[1873:817768] Metal API Validation Enabled
session active state
didReceiveApplicationContext
    ["heartRate": 91BPM]
Optional(91BPM)
Optional("91BPM")
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file Trainer_/ViewController.swift, line 58
2021-03-11 12:45:05.887523-0700 Trainer+[1873:817966] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file Trainer_/ViewController.swift, line 58
```

the func session(didReceiveApplicationContext), from watchconnectivity is working as intended. I believe that my problem comes from me moving the heartRate label to a 'view container'. I added the watchconnectivity at the same time that I moved the label and assumed that it would work.

This may require a different question, not sure, how can i pass data along multiple view controllers that are visible at the same time. Since I am creating the session on the ViewController, I don't yet know how to pass the data to other view controllers without passing a full 'self' reference of the ViewController, to the DetailViewController. Coming from Java and PHP, i feel like this is not good coding practice.

I am thinking about extensions/delegates, and prototypes. I understand them to a slight degree, but I am currently working on an app and my main goal is to have a working prototype. I'll come back and refactor the code fix and fix any gaping vulnerabilities. If any body with experience can provide me with any reliable resources. Tired of hitting the next page of google as i cant find the answers that I am looking for lol.

Answer (score 1):

If you have copied and pasted your code, I think it's just misspelling.
You may try changing this line:

```
print(applicationContext["hearRate"])
```

to:

```
print(applicationContext["heartRate"])
```

Comment: This was my code, fairly new to Swift and iOS dev in general. I found the issue is with the IBOutlet.  The typo was ignored due to my focus on other sections were i had more experience. Can you provide any info or reliable articles that helps pass data across multiple view controllers that are all active at the same time?

I am thinking about extensions/delegates, and prototypes. I understand them to a slight degree, but I am currently working on an app and my main goal is to have a working prototype. I'll come back and refactor after im happy with the prototype.